# php_ssh2.dll for PHP 5.3.1 on WinXP Pro sp3

Tags: php, windows

I had PHP 5.2.2 installed on a previous box (also WinXP Pro sp3) and had gotten the SSH2 extension from http://pecl4win.php.net/ext.php/php_ssh2.dll.

Sadly that server seems to be out of commission for now (*"The pecl4win build box is temporarily out of service. We're preparing a new build system."*). The old DLL doesn't work with the new PHP and I do not have MS Visual Studio 6 to compile it.

Anyone have any idea where I can get this file for PHP 5.3.1?  Or perhaps I should just roll back to PHP 5.2.2?

I should mention that I'm using XAMPP 1.7.3 which has Apache 2.2. So I need DLL's compiled with VC6.

Comment: "I don't have MS Visual Studio" - the visual c++ 2008 expression edition would suffice. see http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/

Comment: VolkerK: Would Visual C++ 2008 produce VC6 DLL's for Apache 2.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download vc6 version of php_ssh2 from here http://www.webvamp.co.uk/uploads/2011/02/php_ssh2-5.3.X-VC6-apache.zip

Comment: Thx JKS. Of course, so many months later, I've actually left the company I was with when I needed this. I'm now developing on OSX for Linux targets. But this does look like it would have worked. Too bad it wasn't available when I was doing my search. (I'm guessing from the URL it was uploaded Feb 2011.)

Answer (score 4):

There are two versions of `lib_ssh2` on http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ :

- `php_ssh2-svn20091128-5.3-nts-vc9-x86.zip`
- `php_ssh2-svn20091128-5.3-vc9-x86.zip`

Those are VC9 versions, which means they should not be used with binaries from Apache.org *(I suppose they are for IIS ? see the left column of http://windows.php.net/ about VC6 vs VC9 )* ; you didn't say which web-server you were using, so maybe...

*(I didn't provide the direct links on purpose : those might get outdated quickly, and I didn't want that for an answer on SO)*

Comment: Thx Pascal.  I'm using Apache 2.2.  Part of XAMPP (which I now notice I didn't list in my original post.  Sorry about that.)

I followed your link to http://windows.php.net and did download the two DLL's, just in case.  Here's what I got when restarting Apache:

>>>
PHP Startup: ssh2: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9
PHP compiled with buildID=API20090626,TS,VC6
These options must match
<<<

Oooh!  So close!

Comment: that is because uses diferent versions of the msvcrt (Microsoft Visual C++ Run Time), you could use a vc9 version of php, try download the lastest from the official page.


And a php modules does not have NOTHING releated to apache, except the php apache SAPI.

Answer (score 2):

Well after searching a lot i found the php_ssh2.dll for my Php 5.2.X VC6

Try this URL
http://www.dll-file-download.com/P/php_ssh2.dll.html

Comment: Thx, Manoharan, this looks like it may have done the trick. It was even available when I was doing my search. If they had mentioned VC6 in there, I might even have found it. SEO: so important.

Comment: Note: This dll appears to be compiled for the Thread Safe version of PHP 5.2 VC6. It can't be used in the Non Thread Safe version.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the official PECL releases, with builds for 5.3, 5.4, and 5.5:

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/0.12/

Comment: Thanks @BradenAnderson, this will be useful to others finding this question.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but no time to compile all that stuff. However I found an other solution, to execute linux-bash scripts on a remote ssh server: [Putty + Plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) + PHP's exec()

With this tools, it is possible to open ssh connections with putty via command line, executed through PHP's [exec, system or passthrough](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/book.exec.php) functions.

Of course this is not as that elegant as ssh-functions for PHP, but maybe this helps someone for it's problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Rudi. But this would be a Windows-specific solution, and I was just developing on Windows, for a Linux target. Still, a clever hack.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. extract php_ssh2.dll file and paste in /ext folder
2. make following entry in php.ini

   ```
    extension=php_ssh2.dll;
   ```
3. restart apache
4. check php.ini for changes